# how to convert any data type to string in C (without knowing it type)

Tags: c, string, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a function takes any number of arguments formats it and print it out to console. I would like Function to have following signature

```
void formatted_text(...);
```

And I would like this function to be called in following way.

```
formatted_text("String 1", 1, "String 2", 2.2);
```

Now the problem is that, in the function I do not know which argument is of which datatype. One solution is I can ask user to convert all of the arguments to string and then pass it to the function like this

```
formatted_text("String 1", "1", "String 2", "2.2");
```

but it wouldn't be as convenient to use. Another thing I can do is ask user to provide datatype for each argument which is again not a very good solution.

Is there a way to convert any datatype to string without knowing its datatype. I know the answer......, but you might know something which I do not.

What would be the best way to handle this king of requirement.

Comment: Using elipsis without a parmeer before them that helps you determine the types of the extra parameters is impossible (if the type is of interest to you). There is a reason `printf` uses a format specifier string.

Comment: Why do you think that `printf` makes you use `%s`, `%d`, *etc*?

Comment: It was a split second difference @paddy :)

Answer (score 2):

C data types are not inherently self-describing, like they often are in other languages like Java, Python, PHP, etc. You **have** to provide some metadata so `formatted_text(...)` can know how to interpret the bytes you are passing it on the stack. As the comments mention, the format string (i.e. the first parameter) you pass to `printf` is one such form that metadata could take.

Answer (score 1):

You have two parts to your problem: wanting a print function that takes a variable number of arguments and is convenient; and wanting a good way for arbitrary user-defined data types to be printed.

For the first part, you could write a "varargs" function, the same sort as `printf()`.  But you have a problem: there is no way to get a count of how many arguments there are and you don't know the types of the arguments.  You could make a function simpler than `printf()` if you say that every argument has to be a pointer to a string, and the last argument must always be a `NULL` pointer; then you can write a simple loop that goes until it hits the `NULL`.  Google search for `c varargs` to find out more.

If you do this you could make a macro that always expands to a call to your function with a `NULL` as the last argument, to make it less likely the users will forget to put the `NULL`.  Something like this:

```
#define CONVENIENT_PRINT(...) \
    my_convenient_print_function(__VA_ARGS__, NULL)
```

Of course the fun part is that some compilers work great with the above, but a few don't.  Writing a macro with variable number of arguments is not as portable as some other parts of C.  But the above form works in Microsoft C and in GCC and Clang, so you are probably fine with it.

For the second part, C doesn't give you much help.  I can suggest two possible solutions to the problem.  The first is to have a rigorous naming convention, to make it easy for users to figure out what function to call; for any data type `FOO` there will always be a function `StringFromFoo()` and the users must learn to call the correct function.  The second is to implement your own object-oriented types, and make sure that each object has a pointer to a method function called `ToString()` or whatever.  Something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char const *(*ToString)(void const *this);
} FOO_CLASS;  // class struct
static FOO_CLASS _foo_class;

char const *FooToString(void const *this)
{
    return NULL; // yeah I'm not really implementing this here
}
_foo_class.ToString = FooToString;

typedef struct
{
    // member variables go here
    int x;
    float f;
    // need a reference back to the class; just one
    FOO_CLASS *pclass;
} FOO;  // instance struct

int InitFoo(int x, float f, FOO **ppfooNew)
{
    FOO *pfoo = malloc(sizeof(FOO));
    if (!pfoo)
    {
        *ppfooNew = NULL;
        return ENOMEM;
    }
    pfoo->x = x;
    pfoo->f = f;
    pfoo->pclass = &_foo_class;

    *ppfooNew = pfoo;
    return 0; // success!
}
// in your code:
FOO *pfoo;
char const *str;

if (InitFoo(x, f, &pfoo))
    goto crash_and_burn;

str = pfoo->pclass->ToString(pfoo);
```

Wow, that's a lot more annoying than an object-oriented language!  That's object-oriented code, but C doesn't help you at all; you have to do all the work yourself.

Note how we use `pfoo` to lookup the class, then find the method function in the class, and *then* we still have to pass `pfoo` in as the argument (the `this` pointer) for the method function.  C++ does all this for you.

At least you could make a macro for the common work of calling the method function:

```
#define STR(instance) \
    (instance)->pclass->ToString(instance)

str = STR(pfoo);
```

For this simple example, we only have one function in the class.  For a real example you would probably have more functions than that!  For a single function you could just put it into the instance and it would be less work, but that doesn't scale, and if you do this at all you should do it consistently.

So, I think most people would go with the naming convention solution, and call that good enough.  I wrote a large project in a partially object-oriented style, and I think it helped make the code more manageable.  And even in the object-oriented style I still had lots of naming conventions.

P.S. You might have noticed that the above code doesn't actually implement `ToString()`, and it will actually be sort of annoying to implement that.  Where will the string go?  If your needs are brutally simple, you could just use a static buffer inside the `ToString()` function, but that's not a good solution... otherwise you need to change `ToString()` to pass in a buffer, or make it call `malloc()` to get a new string buffer; then handle possible failure of `malloc()`; then somehow call `free()` when done with the string (or just shamefully leak memory!).  This is yet more stuff that C++ would do for you... you could create a `std::string`, pass it around, and when it falls out of scope the destructor would be called.